# SCILAB graphics on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, graphics, 22.04, scilab, plot

**SCILAB 6.1.1** works on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but does not produce graphics. Earlier versions such as 5.5.2 also does not produce complete graphics. I have tried plot, plot2d, and bar. Each just produces a graphic window and hangs up.

Everything worked fine on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on the same laptop. Earlier versions of SCILAB  also worked fine on the same laptop.

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all updated Ubuntu from version 20.04 to 22.04 and got same behavior: graphic in scilab is not working any more.
Tried a new installation of scilab 6.1.1 on another labtop with ubuntu 22.04. Scilab is working but we got not graphics.
It seems that the problem is related to java

Franz

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackExchange! You have used the "answer" fuction to make a comment though :-(